# Can I get MapBox layers, with React.js MapBox GL JS, that have been created in MapBox Studio?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have setup several layers in MapBox Studio and I access this map with MapBox GL JS. I wonder if it is possible to access those layers with React.js and not only layers that I have created dynamically with React.js?

I tried with `map.getStyle().layers` but this did not work as it returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most definitely can! To do so, you need to use the `getLayer()` method that is available on the map object (check the docs [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/)
).

I have included a snippet below from a React app using Mapbox. After you create your map, setup a load event listener and then call the `getLayer()` method within the callback.

The `getLayer` method expects an argument for the layer ID which you can just grab from Mapbox Studio. The layer ID is just the layer label that is present in the sidebar in Mapbox Studio. In my example below, "utah-avalanche-paths" is the name I gave my layer in my Mapbox Studio map style.

Hope this helps! I am in the middle of writing a Mapbox and React Deep Dives blog post series. One of my recent posts on [A Complete Guide to Sources and Layers in React and Mapbox GL JS](https://www.lostcreekdesigns.co/writing/a-complete-guide-to-sources-and-layers-in-react-and-mapbox-gl-js) might help you too.

```js
// create the map and configure it
// check out the API reference for more options
// https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: mapContainer.current,
  // custom Mapbox Studio map style url
  style: "mapbox://styles/lcdesigns/ckkuethsm0tzs17s4ibit7nag",
  center: [-111.75, 40.581],
  zoom: 12,
});

// only want to work with the map after it has fully loaded
// if you try to add sources and layers before the map has loaded
// things will not work properly
map.on("load", () => {
  // grab the map layer you want
  // 'utah-avalanche-paths' refer to the layer name in Mapbox Studio
  const layer = map.getLayer("utah-avalanche-paths");
});
```